# TYPO3 8.7.27: Segment was not a keyword for a postVarSet

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, realurl

I'm installing an existing TYPO3 project. After a lot of trying, we managed to get the typo3 backend ready. However, when I go to the website I always get this error message. This probably has something to do with the multilingualism of the website and with the realurl extension.

[image]

composer.json (at root /var/www/html/typo3)

```
{
    "repositories": [{
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "Bm/ah-contentapi",
                "version": "0.0.1",
                "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://user@bitbucket.org/comp/ah_config_typo3.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "Bm/ah-contentelements",
                "version": "0.0.1",
                "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://user@bitbucket.org/comp/ah_contentelements_typo3.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
    "description": "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "require": {
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^4.9.3 || ^5.2",
        "typo3/cms-about": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-context-help": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-documentation": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-form": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-func": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-info-pagetsconfig": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-wizard-crpages": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms-wizard-sortpages": "^8.7.10",
        "typo3/cms": "^8.7",
        "dmitryd/typo3-realurl": "2.*",
        "GridElementsTeam/Gridelements": "8.2.*",
        "clickstorm/cs_seo": "3.*",
        "Bm/ah-contentapi": "0.0.1",
        "Bm/ah-contentelements": "0.0.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure",
            "typo3cms install:generatepackagestates"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "web-dir": "public"
        },
        "helhum/typo3-console": {
            "comment": "This option is not needed ay more for helhum/typo3-console 5.x",
            "install-extension-dummy": false
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Bm\\AhContentelements\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/ah_contentelements/Classes",
            "Bm\\AhContentapi\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/ah_contentapi/Classes"
        }
    }
}
```

realurl_autoconf.php at location:
/var/www/html/typo3/public/typo3conf/ext/ah_contentapi

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'init' =>
            array(
                'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
                'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
            ),
        'pagePath' =>
            array(
                'rootpage_id' => '1',
            ),
        'fileName' =>
            array(
                'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
                'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 0,
                'index' =>
                    array(
                        'print' =>
                            array(
                                'keyValues' =>
                                    array(
                                        'type' => 98,
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
        'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                'api' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ahcontentapi_api[type]',
                        'valueMap' => array(
                            'json' => 'json',
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ahcontentapi_api[controller]',
                        'valueMap' => array(
                            'pages' => 'Pages',
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ahcontentapi_api[action]',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ahcontentapi_api[uid]'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

realurl extension conf:

[image]

Comment: as @Johannes-Nielsen wrote: what is your `realurl` configuration file? the active configuration file is decided in the extension configuration (in the extension manager). the default value is `typo3conf/realurl_autoconf.php`. you might change it to PHP-format and use such a file from your site extension e.g. `typo3conf/ext/site_extension/Configuration/realurl_conf.php`

Comment: I found the realurl_autoconf.php file. It was placed at /var/www/html/typo3/public/typo3conf/ext/ah_contentapi

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ is this a fault in my composer.json?

Comment: that probably has nothing to do with composer. the error message is a typical error of `realurl` when the language coding in the url path is faulty. so we should concentrate on the realurl config. Are you sure this file is configured to use with realurl? (it should not be named with anything **auto**)

Comment: I don't have any realurl_conf.php in the project.. I uploaded a picture with all the files in the ext/realurl directory..

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I now have a realurl_autoconf.php file in the typo3conf folder with:
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']=unserialize('a:1:{s:8:"_DEFAULT";a:4:{s:4:"init";a:2:{s:18:"appendMissingSlash";s:18:"ifNotFile,redirect";s:19:"emptyUrlReturnValue";s:1:"/";$

Comment: as you have multiple realurl config files we need to know which one is active. Therefore I added an (preliminary answer with screenshots how to identify the active config file. please edit your question and add that file. also you can remove `ext_emconf.php` and `composer.json`

Answer (score 0):

as you have multiple realurl files it is important to know which one is used.

[image]
in the TYPO3 BackEnd go to the extension manager module, (1)
filter for 'realurl' (2)
and enter the configuration for the extension (3).

then have a view to the configuration:
[image]
in the first field (**`Path to configuration file`** / `basic.configFile (string)`) you find the active file.

for a better readability you should select "PHP source (slow)" in the field **`Automatic configuration file format`**/ `basic.autoConfFormat (options)` (it is not noticable slower).

Please show that active realurl config file.

Comment: The active conf file is the "typo3conf/realurl_conf.php" It doesn't exist

Comment: then your solution can be to let it be generated automatically (use PHP modus). after that you can add further configuration. e.g. languages, news, other records. Or you copy one of the other files to that location/name. be sure to have a version which covers all topics you need (e.g. languages).

Comment: I changed my configuration page and added the config file in the original question above.

Comment: I added "'preVars' => array(...) to the file and now there is non error anymore. But I get a lot of ### embed() ### or Not Defined tags on the home page